# Hash algorithm to put a specific number of digits into a fixed number of buckets

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

I want to cram 10 base 10 digits (0 to 9,999,999,999) into 6 hex digits (00 00 00 to FF FF FF). I know there will be collisions and that's fine. I also don't need to worry about a separate chain for the collisions to be housed in. Also, I don't need to convert from the hash back into the original. Just need to have a set number of buckets (6 hex digits in 3 bytes) that can be represented as 00 00 00 to FF FF FF. So yes, there will be many numbers in 0 to 9,999,999,999 that map to those buckets...that's fine.

Does anyone know of a good algorithm to do that or perhaps a package in Java/Kotlin?

Comment: Since you don't seem to care about collisions, I think the easiest solution would be `Long.toHexString(value)`, and then call `String#substring` if the `String` is longer than 6 characters. Maybe add a modulus operation if you want to distribute the values a bit more evenly.

Comment: Calculate the modulus? Or bitwise AND?

Comment: Since we don't know what your purpose is, and you've dismissed every usual concern with hashing and not specified any concerns that *do* matter, we can't really say what's a "good" way - only what's a way that would work.  To that end, mjuarez's answer is as good as any with the given info.  But beware - if there are unstated concerns - e.g. about (un)predictability or distribution in a given scenario - this may or may not meet them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to simply use `mod` on the base 10 number

```
base_var_value % 16777215
```

That 16M number is simply `FF FF FF` in hex.

Comment: The simplest approach is bitwise AND (at least for the CPU)

Comment: That's true -- `base_var_value & 0x00FFFFFF`

Comment: @huysentruitw - Not exactly.  To talk about what's efficient for the processor you have to assume you know how the input value is represented.  The one thing we can say for sure is, it's not a 32-bit integer if the range goes to (10 billion - 1).  If it's a 64-bit int, and if the processor in question can directly operate on 64-bit ints, then `&` is likely efficient; but given only what we know, the *mathematical* operation of "mod 0xFFFFFF" is all we can really say.  (Besides, talking this level of optimization in almost all contexts in ridiculous.)

Comment: The mod is fine for what I need (and I thought for non powers of 2 it was just as fast as a bitwise AND, but again...in this case...I don't care). Thanks.